# Meteor Shutdown/Restart Interrupting Running Server-Side Functions

Tags: javascript, meteor, backend

I am building out a data analysis tool in Meteor and am running into issues with the Meteor server shutdown and restart. Server-side, I am pinging several external APIs on a `setInterval`, trimming the responses down to just new data that I haven't already captured, running a batch of calculations on that new data, and finally storing the computed results in Mongo. For every chunk of new data that I receive from the external APIs, there are about 15 different functions/computations that I need to run, and each of the 15 outputs are being stored in Mongo inside separate documents. Client-side, users can subscribe to any one out of the 15 documents, enabling them to view the data in the manner in which they please.

```
new data is captured from the API as {A} and {A} is stored in Mongo
|
begin chain
  |
  function1 -> transforms {A} into {B} and stores {B} in Mongo
  |
  function2 -> transforms {A} into {C} and stores {C} in Mongo
  |
  ...
  |
  function15 -> transforms {A} into {P} and stores {P} in Mongo
  |
end chain
```

The problem, is that when I shut down Meteor, or deploy new code to the server (which will automatically restart the server), the loop that iterates through these functions is being interrupted. Say, functions 1-7 ran successfully, and then Meteor restarted, causing functions 8-15 to never run (or even worse, for function 8 to be interrupted while 9-15 never ran). This causes my documents to no longer be in sync with {A} data that was stored before the loop began.

How can this risk be mitigated? Is it possible, to tell Meteor to gracefully shutdown / wait until this process has completed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a graceful shutdown, and even if there were one, I'm not sure I'd trust it...

What I'd do is assign a `complete` flag to {A} that is triggered when `function15` is finished. If the functions are async (or just expensive, but I doubt that's your case...), then create a record in {B}:{P} when {A} is created with the `_id` of {A} and a `complete` flag.

Regardless, run the functions on a query of batches where `complete` is false.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no official way of a graceful shutdown. So you would have to come up with some other way of making sure your data isn't stored in a inconsistent state.

The easiest way that comes up in my mind would be to disable meteor automatic restarts with `meteor --once`.

Then add a shutdown mode to your application.

In shutdown mode your application should not pick up new tasks only finish what it is currently working on. This would be easy to do if you use [meteor-synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) which has a stop method which doesn't kill currently running functions.

Make sure that a task finishing never leaves a document in a inconsistent state.
So you can have multiple tasks working on a document just make sure that when task1 finishes the document will always be in a state to be picked up by task2.